# Avoid using instance variables in partials views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `@productrecords` and `@clone_record` in controller method. While deploying the following code into staging,

```
= f.association :product, :collection => Category.products,:include_blank => "Select Product",:label => "* Product", :selected =>@productrecords.product_id ? @productrecords.product_id : @clone_record.product_id
```

I get an error "Avoid using instance variables in partials views" in houndci bot.

What is the best practice to fix this issue?

Comment: Where is this line located, in a partial?

Comment: you can render partial as `<%= render partial: 'products', collection: Category.products, locals: {size: 30} %>`

Comment: Yes. Its in a partial file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Yes. It is located in a partial file

That's what the warning/error *tells you*: don't use instance variables **in partial files**. Rather, use local variables. Example:

Your partial render looks something like this:

```
= render 'my_partial'
```

Change it like this to pass all variables explicitly:

```
= render 'my_partial', productrecords: @productrecords, clone_record: @clone_record
```

And your partial will use the locals now:

```
= f.association :product, :collection => Category.products,:include_blank => "Select Product",
               :label => "* Product", 
               :selected =>productrecords.product_id ? productrecords.product_id : clone_record.product_id
```

Comment: Thank you ji. Great